# Dockerized Localstack Terraform Cannot Create Simple Resource

Tags: docker-compose, terraform, localstack, aws-rest-api

I have a simple setup where I only want to start localstack through docker-compose, then run a terraform file to create an aws_api_gateway_rest_api resource. However, it fails to connect to localstack's restapis endpoint "http://localhost:4567/restapis".

Here is the code for docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - 4566:4566
      - 4567:4567
      - 4569:4569
      - 4572:4572
      - 4574:4574
      - 4575:4575
      - 4576:4576
      - 4593:4593
      - 4510-4559:4510-4559
    environment:
      - SERVICES=restapis,s3,lambda,dynamodb,sns,sqs,apigateway,iam
```

Here is the code for main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"

  endpoints {
    s3      = "http://localhost:4572"
    lambda  = "http://localhost:4574"
    dynamodb = "http://localhost:4569"
    sns     = "http://localhost:4575"
    sqs     = "http://localhost:4576"
    apigateway = "http://localhost:4567"
    iam     = "http://localhost:4593"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example_api" {
  name = "example_api"
}
```

Commands:

```
terraform init

terraform plan

terraform apply
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: creating API Gateway REST API (example_api): RequestError: send request failed
│ caused by: Post "http://localhost:4567/restapis": read tcp 127.0.0.1:46738->127.0.0.1:4567: read: connection reset by peer
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't restapis be available on that port? I am able to hit the S3 endpoint (and various others) with no problems.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the example from the localstack GitHub repo: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I have and I get the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your issue, as I'm missing some essential info, such as versions; however, here are a few ideas to get things working: it looks like you're using an older version, and LocalStack does not maintain earlier versions, so you're encouraged to use the latest image, with this [docker-compose file](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). With that, all services are standardized to listen on port `4566`. Lastly, to simplify things, please use the provided [terraform wrapper](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/terraform/#using-the-tflocal-script), `tflocal`, which automatically configures the local service endpoints, allowing you to run the same config file as you would on AWS.
Hope this helps.